# Xcode: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this message from Xcode

```
Ld /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-gqsubryokdmrjmczxeqypzcgpths/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myApp normal armv7
    cd /Users/myUsername/Documents/_IPAD/myApp
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"


/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-gqsubryokdmrjmczxeqypzcgpths/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-gqsubryokdmrjmczxeqypzcgpths/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-gqsubryokdmrjmczxeqypzcgpths/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework AudioToolbox -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework MessageUI -framework CoreData -framework AVFoundation -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/myUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-gqsubryokdmrjmczxeqypzcgpths/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myApp



Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What exactly is not found? If it is saying that something was not found where is this not found stuff being looked for? Or in other words, if xcode is searching for something it is searching somewhere, where and what?

Comment: @Till - you mean the "copy bundle resources" part? yes, I have checked there and I see ViewController.xib there and it is not red. Any other place I can check?

Comment: No, I mean the compile sources section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ViewController` object is not found and it was referenced within `AppDelegate`. You do not link ViewController into your app. Check if your `Compile Sources` section within the `Build Phases` of your project shows `ViewController.m`.

[image]

Comment: that's it! Thanks! I am not sure why the file was not there, because this project was created a few moments ago from a brand new project... I thought the guilty was ViewController.xib not being found... thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: this seems to be happening to me more and more since Xcode 4.2.3, especially when I copy objects from one project to another, you must be very careful to make sure you check the "add to Target" check box. Usually when I get the message as above I add to compile sources.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this.  Turns out I didn't add the new source to all of the targets that needed it.  Maybe this will help someone in the future.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got same error after updating xCode 6beta to xCode 6.0.1. After spending a lot of time I fixed it by deleting "**Derived Data**" from **Window -> Organizer -> Projects -> #Select project#** and pressed Delete in the "Derived Data".